# Stream из Array<Array>

Tags: kotlin, java-stream

Как мне получить поток из Item массива `Array<Array<Item>>`?

Answer (score 2):

`items.flatten().stream()` - то же самое, что и в вашем ответе. Только что ваше решение, что `flatten` создают лишнюю коллекцию. Это может быть быстрее на маленьких коллекциях, но на больших уже будет приводить ко всё большим потерям производительности.
Это можно исправить, избежав создание этой лишней коллекции:

`Arrays.stream(items).flatMap { Arrays.stream(it) }`

Но `Stream` - это java api, в Котлине есть свой **эквивалент** - [Sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html), с более удобным Api, заточенным под Котлин.

`items.asSequence().flatMap { it.asSequence() }`

Comment: Вау. Было приятно узнать про Sequence. По производительности они сравнимы?

Comment: @Roman я не измерял, но что в Sequence, что в Stream заложена одна и та же идея ленивых вычислений при работе с потоками данных, больших различий быть не должнл

Answer (score 0):

```
val temp = ArrayList<Item>()
val items = Array<Array<Item>>()

override fun getAllItems(): Stream<Item>
{
    temp.clear()
    items.forEach { it.forEach { temp.add(it) } }
    return temp.stream()
}
```

Comment: `items.flatten().stream()` - то же самое. Только что ваше решение, что flatten создают лишнюю коллекцию

Comment: @IR42 Оформите ваш коммент как ответ

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Может, наведет на нужные мысли. Реализация на `Java`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "b", "c", "_"));
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("D", "e", "f", ".."));

lists.add(list1);
lists.add(list2);

lists.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).forEach(System.out::print); // Abc_Def..
```